# Clone PHP object and set protected property on clone

Tags: php, object, properties, clone

I got a logical problem.

I got an object that needs to be cloned.

The object is|has a result of a calculation.

The object has a runtime.

In some cases it is faster to clone the object instead of calculating the result again

*(f.e. same parameter ^= same result)*.

**But** the runtime must **not** be copied.

The runtime would be the time to determine that i can use the same result (object).

Example:

```
class Object
{
    protected $runtime;

    public function getRuntime()
    {
        return $this->runtime;
    }

    public function doSome(/*...*/)
    {
        $start = microtime(true);
        // ... the heavy work ...
        // ...
        $this->runtime = microtime(true) - $start;
    }
}

$objects = [];
while (/*...*/) {
    if (count($objects) > 0) {
        $start = microtime(true);
        if (/*check if would get the same result as the previous one*/) {
            $object = clone end($objects);
            // MUST change the runtime here on the clone 
            // but i should not make :runtime public
            $object->runtime = microtime(true) - $start; // :(
            $objects[] = $object;
            continue;
        }
    }
    $object = new Object();
    $object->doSome(/*...*/);
    $objects[] = $object;
}
```

How could i clone the previous object and set the actual runtime on the clone without making it possible to make the runtime property public?

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. Instead, you may either chose an answer below by clicking the checkmark, or by answering the question yourself. Your question has been rolled back to it's previous state. For more information, please visit the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to put this logic in separated method `Object::clone()` like this:

```
class Object
{
    protected $runtime;

    public function getRuntime()
    {
        return $this->runtime;
    }

    public function doSome(/*...*/)
    {
        $start = microtime(true);
        // ... the heavy work ...
        // ...
        $this->runtime = microtime(true) - $start;
    }

    public static function clone($clonable, $runtime)
    {
        $clone = clone $clonable;
        $clone->runtime = $runtime; // we can access it since we are in Object scope
        return $clone;
    }
}

$objects = [];
while (/*...*/) {
    if (count($objects) > 0) {
        $start = microtime(true);
        if (/*check if would get the same result as the previous one*/) {
            $object = Object::clone(end($objects), microtime(true) - $start);
            $objects[] = $object;
            continue;
        }
    }
    $object = new Object();
    $object->doSome(/*...*/);
    $objects[] = $object;
}
```

Another option is just to implement setter method for `runtime` property

Comment: Many thanks. Does make sense to me. Except i dont really understand why we can set a protected property on an object from "outside". But this works. Great! :)

Comment: Since i am not allowed to add a solution example on my own question: i count the time to clone the object in the clone method. I then add the "time to clone" to the given parameter `$runtime`. This provides the complete time to create that object. Perhaps you could add that to your solution. `$start = microtime(true); $clone = clone $clonable; $clone->runtime = $runtime + (microtime(true) - $start); return $clone;`

Comment: Okay, I think it depends on your context where to calculate `runtime`, yeah it can be done in `clone` method too. Also [php.net docs (about private and protected properties access)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Use the magic method:

> Once the cloning is complete, if a __clone() method is defined, then the newly created object's __clone() method will be called, to allow any necessary properties that need to be changed.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone

```
class Object
{
    protected $runtime;

    public function __clone() {
        //set $this->runtime
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the `$start` variable to that method?

Comment: You cannot. `Fatal error: Method Object::__clone() cannot accept any arguments`